# How to use SPARQL Filter query function in prolog query

Tags: prolog, rdf, sparql, allegrograph

I want to query those persons from RDF graphdatabse who are traveled at the same location and at the same date or ovelapped date. We have persons information with travlel location and  their fromdata and todate.  I am running the following query in SPARQL it gives correct result.

SPARQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p1 ?p2 ?o1 ?o2 ?loc ?fd1 ?td1 ?fd2 ?td2
WHERE {
    ?p1 ns:hasTravelledAt ?o1 .
    ?p2 ns:hasTravelledAt ?o2 .
    ?o1 ns:hasLocation ?loc .
    ?o2 ns:hasLocation ?loc .
    ?o1 ns:fromDate ?fd1 .
    ?o2 ns:fromDate ?fd2 .
    ?o1 ns:toDate ?td1 .
    ?o2 ns:toDate ?td2 .
  FILTER ( (?p1 != ?p2 ) && ( (?fd1 <= ?fd2 && ?fd2 <= ?td1) || (?fd2 <= ?fd1 && ?fd1 <= ?td2) ) )
}
```

Now I want to write the same query in Prolog but I am having issue with Filter function how can I replace Sparql Filter function in Prolog query: I am trying to run the query as follows: but not getting the result:

```
(select-distinct (?p1 ?p2 ?o1 ?o2 ?loc ?fd1 ?td1 ?fd2 ?td2)
 (q ?p1 !ns:hasTravelledAt ?o1)
 (q ?p2 !ns:hasTravelledAt ?o2)
 (q ?o1 !ns:hasLocation ?loc)
 (q ?o2 !ns:hasLocation ?loc)
 (q ?o1 !ns:fromDate ?fd1)
 (q ?o2 !ns:fromDate ?fd2) 
 (q ?o1 !ns:toDate ?td1)
 (q ?o2 !ns:toDate ?td2) 
?- (or (and (?fd1 <= fd2) (?fd2 <= ?td1))  (and (?fd2 <= fd1) (?fd1 <= ?td2)) )
(not (= ?p1 ?p2))
 )
```

Can any one help me? How can I use filter function in prolog query.
Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're using AllegroGraph?  The prolog syntax you're using isn't standard prolog, and the only graph database I know of that provides both SPARQL and Prolog interfaces is AllegroGraph (Jena's backwards rule engine is similar, but clearly not what you're using here).

Comment: Yes Joshua, you are right I am using AllegroGraph.